SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed
I'm referencing the example here, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-dotnet-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/1-sign-in-aspnet-core-mvc, to create a web app that authenticates against Azure AD.
I first created a new app in Visual Studio 2022 using the template "ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)". For the template options, I selected .NET 8.0 and used the default selections for everything else.
I then added this to appsettings.json.

I then added some code to program.cs to get this.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

var app = builder.Build();

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

After that I ran the program and got this error: SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. The token's kid is: '8tWTh-ofb4hcd2AWwJLbzyUPQUY', but did not match any keys in TokenValidationParameters or Configuration.
Can someone help me resolve this error?

You can check that your TenantId, ClientId and ClientSecret are valid and correct, and that the relevant NuGet packages versions are the latest.

I've verified that's all correct. Still getting the same error.
